# Edit and Merge ghosting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-10.6

Why is  and what can I do to unghost the "merge" under the EDIT dropdown on my ArcGIS 10.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing by ghost you mean greyed out.

Make sure you have selected the features from a single feature class.

Press the Clear the selected features button. 
Then select the features in the attribute table. 
Try the merge button then.